# webpack path and fs module

Tags: node.js

```
if(fs.existsSync(path.dirname(__dirname)+'/database/logs_models')
```

После сборки возвращает false

Суть такова, что код обрабатывается в момент выполнения, а не в момент сборки...
Следовательно любые попытки чтения файлов будут возвращать false, так как вебпак собрал все в один файл например в папку server
И все account/info
database/index
и т.д., он никогда не найдет, так как по сути этих папок и файлов не существует в том месте где запущен файл (собранный)

Помогите решить проблему

Answer (score 0):

Возможные решения:

- Использование двойного обратного слеша: вместо
  `path.dirname(__dirname)+'/database/logs_models'` используйте `path.dirname(__dirname)+'\\database\\logs_models'`.
- Перенос папок в папку с собранным файлом: если вы используете webpack
  или другой сборщик, то можете перенести папку `database/logs_models` в
  папку с собранным файлом и использовать относительный путь.

Comment: Смысл тогда вебпака в принципе если я все модули перенесу в папку стартового файла?
Спасибо за ответ